# Refere to jobs in sh

Tags: bash, shell, sh, jobs

In bash I can refer to the last job with `%+` or `%%` but I can't do that in `/bin/sh`.

Considering the following script:

```
#!/bin/[ba]sh

some_job() {
    sleep 1
    sleep 1
    sleep 1
    sleep 1
    sleep 1
    sleep 1
}

some_other_job() {
    sleep 1
}

echo "some_job"
some_job &

echo "some_other_job"
some_other_job &

echo "sleep"
sleep 2

kill %1

jobs -l
```

running it with `bash` is fine, but executing it with `sh` gives me an error.

```
$ ./mwe.sh
some_job
some_other_job
sleep
./mwe.sh: 25: kill: No such process

[2] + 2446 Done
[1] + 2445 Running
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2445 pts/0    00:00:00 mwe.sh
 2453 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep
 2494 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
 3587 pts/0    00:00:01 zsh
```

How can I refer to jobs in `/bin/sh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: POSIX `kill` *does* [accept job ids](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html#tag_20_64_05); they just aren't mentioned in the synopsis. [Leon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40387041/1126841) is correct as well.

---

POSIX `kill` only works with process ids, not jobspecs. You'll have to explicitly record the process ID of the job you want to kill.

```
# [ function definitions deleted.]

echo "some_job"
some_job & to_kill=$!

echo "some_other_job"
some_other_job &

echo "sleep"
sleep 2

kill "$to_kill"

jobs -l
```

Answer (score 2):

Try enabling job control in one of the following ways:

1. Change your shebang line to **`#!/bin/sh -m`**
2. Add **`set -m`** as the first command to your script

Both methods worked for me (using `dash` as `/bin/sh`).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the vanilla Bourne Shell does not support job control.

Comment: Does that mean everything I start with `&` gets "out of control"?

Comment: One should assume that `/bin/sh` refers to the POSIX shell, not Bourne shell.

Comment: As chepner says -- Bourne is a 1970s shell. POSIX sh, established in the 90s, is a much newer standard: If modern shells were a superset of Bourne, `echo foo ^ cat` would emit `foo` on stdout, not `foo ^ cat` -- as in Bourne, unlike POSIX sh, `^` is a pipe character.